# Closure of the Laplacian in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, laplacian

Consider the Laplacian $\Delta$ as an operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, densely defined on the subspace $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$.

1. Is the domain of the closure of the Laplacian, in the sense described here:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators,
   equal *exactly* to:
   $$\{u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) | \Delta u \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\}$$
   (where $\Delta$ here means in the distributional sense)?
2. Does any of the above spaces (which I hope are equal) in turn exactly equal the Sobolev space $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R^n)$, or is $W^{2,2}$ actually a strictly smaller space?
3. Does any of the above spaces equal the [Friedrichs extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs_extension)?

Comment: The space you give is indeed equal to $W^{2,2}$. You can show this using the Riesz transform.

Comment: @Jonas - thanks.  That's helpful.

Comment: One of the link is dead, so I remove it. Also, what is $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about Friedrichs extension, so I will only comment on the first two.

I will sketch how to prove that your space with the $2$ replaced by a $p$ is equal to that Sobolev space. For $p = 2$ you can just use Plancherel together with our friend the Fourier transform (try it!).

Using the Riesz transform one can show (See Stein's Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions) that

**Theorem.** Suppose $f \in C^2$ and suppose that $f$ has compact support. Then we have
$$\left \|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} \right \|_p \leq A_p \|\Delta f\|_p \text{  for $1 < p < \infty$}$$

Using limits and so on we can show that this holds for $W^{2, p}(\mathbf{R}^d)$ and with some PDE tricks also for domains.

From this we get

**Corollary.** For $1 < p < \infty$ we have,
$$W^{2, p}(\mathbf{R}^d) = \{f \in L^p(\mathbf{R}^d): \Delta f \in L^p\}.$$

This is quite easy. Just introduce the norm $|\!|\!|f|\!|\!| = \|f\|_p + \|\Delta f\|_p$ and show that this is equivalent to the Sobolev norm. To show this we can use that in $\mathbf R$ we have that $\|f'\|_p \lesssim \|f\|_p + \|f''\|_p$. This is just by integration by parts. A similar formula holds for $\mathbf R^d$.

Comment: You see? Harmonic analysis rocks!

Comment: What is this? Harmonic analysis geology?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes it is.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Does your integration by parts argument still work if we consider the domain of $-\Delta$ to be compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ 0 \}$? I think the closure will have to be $\{ u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \ \vert \ u(0) =0 \}$

Answer (score 5):

To answer your third question, this extension is indeed the Friedrichs extension, because the closure of $\Delta$ is self-adjoint; that is, $\Delta$ is *essentially self-adjoint*.

The Friedrichs extension is a certain distinguished self-adjoint extension of a symmetric operator which is in some sense the "smallest".  However, it is not hard to show that if the closure of an operator is self-adjoint, then it is the unique self-adjoint extension.  So the Friedrichs extension must equal the closure of $\Delta$.

Comment: In particular, I didn't realize about that "smallest" property.  Thanks again!

Comment: Could you give me some reference for the Friedrich extension?

Comment: @PtF: There is a good exposition in Volume 2 of Reed and Simon (Methods of Mathematical Physics: Fourier Analysis and Self-Adjointness).  I think the relevant section is entitled something like "positive quadratic forms"

Comment: Do you have a reference for the essential self-adjointness of $\Delta$? In particular, on Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: I found it: this blog post has links to the original papers by Gaffney and Roelcke: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/#more-5573